# How to create collapse able Menu items in Android?

Tags: android, menu, popup

I am designing an Android Application, in which I want to add a filter to filter the choices that are displayed in certain categories, now the thing is I am planning to have show a PopupMenu whenever a user clicks on the filter button, and it is working, but since the number if filers is large. so I want to group them and make them collapse able, and I have seen many apps doing so, but I am not able to implement than in code, if you could provide me with a nice code doing the same, or any tutorial it would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Like this,http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using json for getting the data, then it will be good to maintain the filter from back end side. So just pass the name of category or categories, for which you want to get filter. and you will get the result from json for all categories. Most of the Apps using this approach. So you can also try this way, to achieve filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly, but if you want to group some items in your popup ExpandableListView should solve your problem.

Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html